# trouble in installing redisBloom

Tags: redis

when i installing RedisBloom, and obey the intrustion of Github RedisBloom tutorial using `./sbin/setup`. The process was stucked in this page.

```
~/redis-stable/RedisBloom$ ./sbin/setup 
E: Release file for http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 13h 23min 46s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 14h 8min 15s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 13h 27min 24s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
```

what's wrong with it? How can i fix it?

> OS: Ubuntu 18.04 in WSL
> redis: 7.0.11

I was already intalled Redis.And I want to install extension RedisBloom.